# Node JS and pg module 'How can I really close connection?'

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm going crazy with node pg module, getting 'too many clients already' error.

My `app.js` file for example, manages some routes in which I query some data to postgres. `app.js` looks like bellow:

```
//First I create a client
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
// Then I use that client to every routes, for example:
ContPg.prototype.someController = function(req, res){
    client.connect(function(error){
        if(error) return console.error('error conectando', error); 
        // Need to close client if there's an error connecting??

        client.query(someQuery, function(e,r){
            client.end(); 
            // Here sometimes I dont end client if i need to query more data 
            if(e) return console.error('error consultando', e);
            // Do anything with result...
        })
    });
}
```

As I said I use that client for all routes in file `pg.js`, but in other files with other routes I do the same to connect to postgres (create client and use for all routes that manage that file)

**Questions**

Is something wrong with my code? I ended wrong client connection?
If there's nothing wrong, what could be causing 'too many clients already' error?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you were to use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), you would not have this problem at all. It opens and closes connections automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try pg-promise module later. I have seen a little and it looks fine and user-friendly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended pattern is to use client pooling. From the [`node-postgres` documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres#client-pooling):

> Generally you will access the PostgreSQL server through a pool of
>   clients. A client takes a non-trivial amount of time to establish a
>   new connection. A client also consumes a non-trivial amount of
>   resources on the PostgreSQL server - not something you want to do on
>   every http request. Good news: node-postgres ships with built in
>   client pooling.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://username:password@localhost/database";

//this initializes a connection pool
//it will keep idle connections open for a (configurable) 30 seconds
//and set a limit of 20 (also configurable)
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['1'], function(err, result) {
    //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
    done();

    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].number);
    //output: 1
  });
});
```

Don't forget to call `done()` or you'll be in trouble!

Comment: Ok, so I should use that pattern for every request and call done() when I don't need that client to query anymore? I will be creting a connection pool for every request. I need to end that connection pool? Sorry if stupid question, but as I said, i'm going crazy with node-postgres. Thanks!!

Comment: For each (web) request where you'll need access to the Postgresql server, you call `pg.connect` to get a client, and once you're done with it, you call `done`.