# Can not close pg-native connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, native, pg

I have connected pgsql database with pg-native but unable to close it once it task is finished.

Here is my code:

```
var pg = require('pg').native;

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
        if(err)
        {
              pg.end();   // end connection here, not working
        }
        // some code
    });
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be closing the connection on the `client`, not on `pg`. Try

```
var pg = require('pg').native;

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    // some code
    if (err) {
       done() // to release the client so that it can reused in a future connection 
       client.end() // to close the connection.
    }
});
```

It's important to release the client by calling `done()`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34804109/3674262) for the explanation

Comment: I have to close connection in error block. Updated question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to close the connection in error block, check it out.

Comment: client is null in error block. you can not do client.end() in this case.