# NodeJs using pg client - Jest has detected the following open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting - TCPWRAP

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jestjs

In some integration tests in my Node.js, I use `pg` to perform some cleanup of the Postgres tests database after the test have run. I call this in the `afterAll()`:

```
afterAll(() => {

  const { Pool } = require('pg')
  const connectionString = 'postgresql://' + PG_USER + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + ':' + PG_PORT + '/' + DATABASE_TEST;
  const pool = new Pool({
   connectionString,
   })

   pool.query('TRUNCATE someTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;', (err, res) => {
       pool.end();
   })
```

When I run Jest tests in my Node.js app, I'm getting the error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

When I add `--detectOpenHandles` to my npm `test` script in `package.json`, I then get the following:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

> 259 |   pool.query('TRUNCATE someTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;', (err, res) => {
      |        ^
  260 |       
  261 |       pool.end();
  262 |   })
```

If I move the connection to the database into a separate file (outside of the `__tests__` folder), the Jest tests still don't exit (with the same error).

If I use a pg `Client` and do this, I get a similar issue with the `client.connect()`

```
  client.connect()
  client
    .query('TRUNCATE someTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;')
    .then(() => client.end())
```

Can anyone explain what's actually going on here? Does Jest try to close after the final test, but the operation in `afterAll()` is preventing this? What do I need to do to allow the tests to exit? None of the solutions in other similar SO questions apply to my case.

**Update**

I tried the suggestion by @Estus Flask, but it still doesn't fix the issue. Using the following (which passes `done` as the callback function, so that the `afterAll` won't complete until `done()` is called (which I call when the `pool.end()` promise resolves):

```
afterAll( done => {

  const { Pool } = require('pg')
  const connectionString = 'postgresql://' + PG_USER + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + ':' + PG_PORT + '/' + DATABASE_TEST;
  const pool = new Pool({
   connectionString,
   })

   pool.query('TRUNCATE someTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;', (err, res) => {
     pool.end().then(done());
   })
  })
});
```

Comment: You're not waiting for the request to end, for starters. Call `done` in innermost callback, or preferably use promises.

Comment: Thanks @Estus Flask. I tried using `done` but it didn't work. Please see my 'update' in the OP. Any ideas?

Comment: At this point it's ok from Jest perspective. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803691/node-js-and-pg-module-how-can-i-really-close-connection . pg-promise is likely the recommended way to do this as Node supports promises for years.

Comment: Also your use of `done` is invalid. It is not `.then(done())`, it is `.then(done)`. There is a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm correct but it doesn't seem like your `pool.end` awaited nor via `await` or via the old-fasion promise.
Try this-

```
afterAll(async () => {

    const { Pool } = require('pg')
    const connectionString = 'postgresql://' + PG_USER + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + ':' + PG_PORT + '/' + DATABASE_TEST;
    const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString,
    })
    
    await pool.query('TRUNCATE someTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;')
    await pool.end()
}
```

Furthermore, as stated below postgres has a limited amount of connections, so, it's always a good practice to close connections, especially on tests.

> By default, all PostgreSQL deployments on Compose start with a connection limit that sets the maximum number of connections allowed to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answers here, micromanaging the pool and the pool client worked for me:

```
describe('My Tests', () => {
    let pool: Pool = null;
    let client: PoolClient = null;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        pool = new Pool(connectionInfo);
        client = await pool.connect();
        .
        .
        .
    }, 10000);

    afterAll(async () => {
        client.release();
        await pool.end();
    }, 10000);

    .
    .
    .
};
```